# Entity Framework 6.1.13 lazy loading and virtual objects disposal

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dao

I've been working with Entity Framework for about 8 months now and I recently updated from version 4 or 5 to 6.1.13.

I wrote the following generic DAO class:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using Entidades;
using Repositorio.Context;

namespace Repositorio.DAO
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Classe generica para operacoes (CRUD) relacionadas com o banco de dados.
    /// Para cada entidade do tipo TBean, um DAO devera ser criado.
    /// </summary>
    public class DAO<TBean> : IDisposable where TBean : Bean
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Set de entidades
        /// </summary>
        protected DbSet<TBean> set;

        /// <summary>
        /// Contexto das entidades
        /// </summary>
        protected DatabaseContext context;

        /// <summary>
        /// Construtor. Inicializa atributos internos.
        /// </summary>
        public DAO()
        {
            context = new DatabaseContext();
            set = context.Set<TBean>();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Destroi este DAO.
        /// </summary>
        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (context != null)
            {
                context.Dispose();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Metodo de commit para transacoes com auto-commit desabilitado
        /// </summary>
        public void SaveChanges()
        {
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Insere ou atualiza um objeto do tipo TBean. Em atualizacoes, todos os atributos sao sobrepostos (atualizados).
        /// </summary>
        public void CreateUpdate(TBean bean, bool commit = true)
        {
            // Se entidade nao tiver um id, ela sera adicionada
            if (bean.Id.Equals(default(int)))
            {
                Create(bean, commit);
            }
            else
            {
                Update(bean, commit);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Cria uma entidade do tipo TBean.
        /// </summary>
        public virtual void Create(TBean bean, bool commit = true, int committer = 0)
        {
            SetBeanState(EntityState.Added, bean, commit);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Atualiza/sobescreve uma entidade do tipo TBean.
        /// </summary>
        public virtual void Update(TBean bean, bool commit = true, int committer = 0)
        {
            SetBeanState(EntityState.Modified, bean, commit);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Deleta uma entidade do tipo TBean.
        /// </summary>
        public virtual void Delete(TBean bean, bool commit = true, int committer = 0)
        {
            SetBeanState(EntityState.Deleted, bean, commit);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Carrega, de forma lazy (preguicosa), todos os resultados de um objeto do tipo TBean.
        /// </summary>
        public virtual IQueryable<TBean> List()
        {
            return ListEager(bean => true, null);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Carrega, de forma lazy (preguicosa), todos os resultados de um objeto do tipo TBean, dado um filtro.
        /// </summary>
        public virtual IQueryable<TBean> List(Expression<Func<TBean, bool>> filter)
        {
            return ListEager(filter, null);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Carrega, de forma eager (gulosa), todos os resultados de um objeto do tipo TBean.
        /// </summary>
        public IQueryable<TBean> ListEager(Expression<Func<TBean, object>> include)
        {
            return ListEager(bean => true, include);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Carrega, de forma eager (gulosa), todos os resultados de um objeto do tipo TBean.
        /// </summary>
        public IQueryable<TBean> ListEager(Expression<Func<TBean, bool>> filter, Expression<Func<TBean, object>> include)
        {
            IQueryable<TBean> query = set.AsQueryable();

            // Se houver includes, valida e adiciona
            if (include != null)
            {
                foreach (var member in RetrieveForeignKeyMembers(include))
                {
                    query = query.Include(member.Name);
                }
            }

            return query.Where(filter);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Procura por um objeto do tipo TBean, dado um identificador
        /// </summary>
        public virtual TBean Search(int id)
        {
            return SearchEager(bean => bean.Id == id, null);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Procura por um objeto do tipo TBean, dado um filtro
        /// </summary>
        public virtual TBean Search(Expression<Func<TBean, bool>> filter)
        {
            return SearchEager(filter, null);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Procura por um objeto do tipo TBean, usando eager loading, dado um identificador.
        /// </summary>
        public TBean SearchEager(int id, Expression<Func<TBean, object>> include)
        {
            return SearchEager(bean => bean.Id == id, include);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Procura por um objeto do tipo TBean, usando eager loading, dado um filtro.
        /// </summary>
        public TBean SearchEager(Expression<Func<TBean, bool>> filter, Expression<Func<TBean, object>> include)
        {
            IQueryable<TBean> query = set.AsQueryable();

            // Se houver includes, valida e adiciona
            if (include != null)
            {
                foreach (var member in RetrieveForeignKeyMembers(include))
                {
                    query = query.Include(member.Name);
                }
            }

            return query.FirstOrDefault(filter);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Retorna todos os membros definidos como chave estrangeira, a partir de uma Expression.
        /// Ex.: 
        ///     1. attr => attr.AlgumaCoisa
        ///     2. attrs => new { attr.AlgumaCoisa, attr.AlgumaOutraCoisa, attr.MaisCoisa }
        /// </summary>
        protected List<MemberInfo> RetrieveForeignKeyMembers(Expression<Func<TBean, object>> expression)
        {
            List<MemberInfo> members = new List<MemberInfo>();

            // Apenas expressoes lambdas sao validas para definicao de uma ForeignKey
            if (expression.NodeType.Equals(ExpressionType.Lambda))
            {
                // Captura membros. Em new expressions, Members nao contem CustomAttributes!
                switch (expression.Body.NodeType)
                {
                    case ExpressionType.MemberAccess:
                        members.Add((expression.Body as MemberExpression).Member);
                        break;
                    case ExpressionType.New:
                        members.AddRange((expression.Body as NewExpression).Arguments.Select(arg => (arg as MemberExpression).Member));
                        break;
                }
            }

            // Para cada membro, checa se este possui um ForeignKeyAttribute
            if (members.Any(member => member.GetCustomAttributes<ForeignKeyAttribute>().Count() == 0))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Include inválido!", "expression");
            }

            return members;
        }

        protected void SetBeanState(EntityState state, TBean bean, bool commit = true)
        {
            // Atributos correspondentes a chave primaria nao podem ser invalidos!
            context.Entry(bean).State = state;

            if (commit)
            {
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I thought it was working as expected, untill yesterday. I noticed that virtual fields were being loaded even with ´LazyLoadingEnabled´ set to true (default) and no Include() calls.

Lets take this bean class as an example (unfortunatelly I cant paste everything, like Bean, IAjustepreco, IAuditable interfaces etc). Also, please note that all the bean configuration are done in Configuration classes. ForeignKey attributes are only used for marking navigation properties, so ignore their "NAVIGATION_PROPERTY" value, since they can't be empty or null. Here goes:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using Entidades.Enums;
using Entidades.Interfaces;
using Entidades.Interfaces.Auditoria;

namespace Entidades
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Ajustes de preco de um determinado material.
    /// Assessores poderao propor novos precos para seus clientes,
    /// submetendo-os a um workflow de aprovacao por parte dos seus gerentes,
    /// superintendente, diretores comerciais e diretor de logistica.
    /// </summary>
    [Table("TB_AJUSTE_PRECO", Schema = "dbo")]
    public class AjustePreco : Bean, IAjustePreco, IAuditable<AjustePrecoAudition>
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Identificador deste objeto.
        /// </summary>
        [Column("ID")]
        public override int Id { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// ID do usuario que solicitou o ajuste (FK).
        /// </summary>
        [Column("ID_USUARIO_SOLICITANTE")]
        public int UsuarioCriador { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Data em que este ajuste foi solicitado.
        /// </summary>
        [Column("DT_SOLICITACAO")]
        public DateTime DataCriacao { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// ID do motivo pelo qual este ajuste foi submetido (FK).
        /// </summary>
        [Column("ID_MOTIVO_SUBMISSAO")]
        public int MotivoSubmissaoId { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// ID do perfil ao qual este ajuste se encontra pendente.
        /// </summary>
        [Column("TP_PERFIL")]
        public PerfilAcesso Perfil { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Estado atual deste ajuste.
        /// </summary>
        [Column("STATUS")]
        public AjustePrecoStatus Status { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Data de validade (vingencia) desse ajuste.
        /// </summary>
        [Column("DT_VALIDADE")]
        public DateTime DataValidade { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Valor do preco final proposto por alguem (assessor).
        /// Este valor sera sugerido como um novo valor para algum material de algum cliente.
        /// </summary>
        [Column("PRECO_FINAL_NOVO")]
        public decimal PrecoFinalNovo { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Valor do preco final do material no momento em que este ajuste foi solicitado (valor atual).
        /// Este valor e utilizado apenas para validacao da atualizacao deste ajuste.
        /// </summary>
        [Column("PRECO_FINAL_ATUAL")]
        public decimal PrecoFinalAtual { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Valor do acrescimo/desconto do material no momento em que este ajuste foi solicitado (valor atual).
        /// </summary>
        [Column("VL_AJUSTE_ATUAL")]
        public decimal ValorAjusteAtual { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Valor do novo ajuste. Em casos onde nao ha imposto ICMS ST, o calculo desta 
        /// variavel sera (PrecoFinalNovo - PrecoFinalAtual) + ValorAjusteAtual.
        /// Caso contrario, havera um webservice para calcular este valor.
        /// Ao concluir o workflow (todas as aprovacoes), este valor sera enviado
        /// para o SAP para substituir o ajuste corrente de um usuario.
        /// </summary>
        [Column("VL_AJUSTE_NOVO")]
        public decimal ValorAjusteNovo { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Nome do cliente favorecido.
        /// </summary>
        [Column("NM_CLIENTE")]
        public string NomeCliente { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Nome do material ao qual este ajuste se refere.
        /// </summary>
        [Column("NM_MATERIAL")]
        public string NomeMaterial { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Nome do centro
        /// </summary>
        [Column("NM_CENTRO")]
        public string NomeCentro { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Nome da condição de pagamento.
        /// </summary>
        [Column("NM_CONDICAO_PAGAMENTO")]
        public string NomeCondicaoPagamento { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Nome da bandeira do cliente.
        /// </summary>
        [Column("NM_BANDEIRA")]
        public string NomeBandeira { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Nome do frete utilizado.
        /// </summary>
        [Column("NM_FRETE")]
        public string NomeFrete { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Id do cliente, no SAP, o qual sera atribuido o ajuste
        /// </summary>
        [Column("CD_CLIENTE")]
        public string CodigoCliente { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Codigo do material, em string, com padding left zeros.
        /// </summary>
        [Column("CD_MATERIAL")]
        public string CodigoMaterial { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Codigo do Centro, em string.
        /// Apesar de nao conter letras em seus codigos, algum dia o tipo de
        /// dados podera ser alterado. Isto explica o tipo 'string'.
        /// </summary>
        [Column("CD_CENTRO")]
        public string CodigoCentro { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Codigo da condição de pagamento: C000, C001 e etc.
        /// </summary>
        [Column("CD_CONDICAO_PAGAMENTO")]
        public string CodigoCondicaoPagamento { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Codigo da bandeira do cliente favorecido.
        /// </summary>
        [Column("CD_BANDEIRA")]
        public string CodigoBandeira { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Codigo do frete utilizado.
        /// </summary>
        [Column("CD_FRETE")]
        public string CodigoFrete { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Distancia entre o cliente e a base mais proxima
        /// </summary>
        [Column("DISTANCIA_ATUAL")]
        public decimal DistanciaAtual { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// [NotMapped]
        /// Usuario que solicitou este ajuste (Navigation property).
        /// </summary>
        [ForeignKey("NAVIGATION_PROPERTY")]
        public Usuario Solicitante { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// [NotMapped]
        /// Motivo de submissao deste ajuste (Navigation property).
        /// </summary>
        [ForeignKey("NAVIGATION_PROPERTY")]
        public AjustePrecoMotivo MotivoSubmissao { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// [NotMapped]
        /// Preco de custo do material ao qual este ajuste se refere.
        /// Esta diretamente relacionada a ZFMSD_CALCULA_PRECO_PORTAL.E_VL_CUSTO_MEDIO_MOVEL.
        /// </summary>
        //[Column("PRECO_CUSTO_MEDIA_MOVEL")]
        [NotMapped]
        public decimal PrecoCustoMediaMovel { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// [NotMapped]
        /// </summary>
        [NotMapped]
        public decimal PrecoCustoUtilizado
        {
            get { return PrecoBase - ValorMargem - ValorOverhead; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// [NotMapped]
        /// Valor da diferenca entre o preco proposto e o preco atual.
        /// </summary>
        [NotMapped]
        public decimal PrecoFinalDelta
        {
            get { return PrecoFinalAtual - PrecoFinalNovo; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// [NotMapped]
        /// Preco base do material ao qual este ajuste se refere.
        /// Este dado e obtido atraves de webservice.
        /// </summary>
        [NotMapped]
        public decimal PrecoBase { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// [NotMapped]
        /// Valor do juros aplicado sobre a condicao de pagamento do material 
        /// ao qual este ajuste se refere.
        /// Este dado e obtido atraves de webservice.
        /// </summary>
        [NotMapped]
        public decimal ValorFinanceiro { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// [NotMapped]
        /// Valor do frete do material ao qual este ajuste se refere.
        /// Este dado e obtido atraves de webservice.
        /// </summary>
        [NotMapped]
        public decimal ValorFrete { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// [NotMapped]
        /// Valor do investimento (ROI) do material ao qual este ajuste se refere.
        /// Este dado e obtido atraves de webservice.
        /// </summary>
        [NotMapped]
        public decimal ValorInvestimento { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// [NotMapped]
        /// Valor do rateio de todas as despesas da empresa incluso ao preco 
        /// de um material, o qual este ajuste se refere.
        /// Este dado e obtido atraves de webservice.
        /// </summary>
        [NotMapped]
        public decimal ValorOverhead { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// [NotMapped]
        /// Margem de lucro de um material ao qual este ajuste se refere.
        /// Este dado e obtido atraves de webservice.
        /// </summary>
        [NotMapped]
        public decimal ValorMargem { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// [NotMapped]
        /// Formula: ValorMargem + ValorInvestimento + ValorAjusteNovo.
        /// </summary>
        [NotMapped]
        public decimal ValorMargemAjustada
        {
            get { return ValorMargem + ValorInvestimento + ValorAjusteNovo; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// [NotMapped]
        /// Formula: PrecoFinalAtual - ValorCustoUtilizado - ValorInvestimento - ValorFrete - ValorFinanceiro.
        /// </summary>
        [NotMapped]
        public decimal ValorMargemBruta
        {
            get { return PrecoFinalAtual - ValorInvestimento - ValorFrete - ValorFinanceiro; } // - ValorCustoUtilizado
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// [NotMapped]
        /// Identifica se este ajuste e um acrescimo ou um desconto.
        /// </summary>
        [NotMapped]
        public bool IsAcrescimo
        {
            get { return PrecoFinalNovo - PrecoFinalAtual > 0M; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Construtor. Configura valores default.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Atributos decimais devem ter as casas decimais configuradas,
        /// caso contrario os valores persistidos serao "0" ao inves de "0.0000".
        /// </remarks>
        public AjustePreco()
        {
            PrecoFinalNovo = 0.0000M;
            PrecoFinalAtual = 0.0000M;
            ValorAjusteAtual = 0.0000M;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Cria seu objeto de auditoria a partir do ponteiro para este objeto
        /// </summary>
        public AjustePrecoAudition CreateAudition()
        {
            return new AjustePrecoAudition(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, the buggy part. This piece of code works as expected:

```
public static IEnumerable<AjustePreco> Listar(bool eager = true)
{
    using (var dao = new AjustePrecoDAO())
    {
        if (eager)
        {
            return new List<AjustePreco>(dao.ListEager(ap => new { ap.Solicitante, ap.MotivoSubmissao }));
        }
        else
        {
            //var x = new List<AjustePreco>(dao.List()); return x; // Navigation properties are set (unexpected)
            return new List<AjustePreco>(dao.List()); // Navigation properties are disposed (expected)
        }
    }
}
```

While this one does not (CAUTION: really weird behavior below):

```
public static void Test(Usuario usuario)
{
    IEnumerable<AjustePreco> x0 = ManterAjustePreco.Listar(false);
    IEnumerable<AjustePreco> x1 = null;
    IEnumerable<AjustePreco> x2 = null;
    IEnumerable<AjustePreco> x3 = null;
    IEnumerable<AjustePreco> x4 = null;

    using (var dao = new AjustePrecoDAO())
    {
        x1 = dao.List().ToList();
        x2 = new List<AjustePreco>(dao.List(u => u.Perfil == PerfilAcesso.Gerente));
        x3 = new List<AjustePreco>(dao.ListEager(i => i.Solicitante));
        x4 = new List<AjustePreco>(dao.ListEager(a => a.Perfil == PerfilAcesso.Gerente, i => i.Solicitante));
    }

    // THIS IS THE WEIRDEST PART:
    // Sometimes, running this same function multiple times would cause an exception in any of the next 3 lines.
    var f = x0.ElementAt(0).MotivoSubmissao;
    var g = x1.ElementAt(0).MotivoSubmissao;
    var h = x2.ElementAt(0).MotivoSubmissao;

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Done");
}
```

This is so weird that I'm not even sure if I could explain it clearly. If something is unclear, please let me know. I'm desperate.

Thanks a lot!

**EDIT:**

After a short discussion with Ivan, I removed the `virtual` keyword from the navigation properties. This lead to the real behavior I was expecting, althought I'm facing another weird thing, as follows:

```
IEnumerable<AjustePreco> x1 = null;
IEnumerable<AjustePreco> x3 = null;

using (var dao = new AjustePrecoDAO())
{
    x1 = dao.List().ToList(); // Gets modified
    x1 = new List<AjustePreco>(dao.List()); // Gets modified
    x1 = new List<AjustePreco>(dao.List()).AsReadOnly(); // Gets modified
    x3 = new List<AjustePreco>(dao.ListEager(i => i.MotivoSubmissao));
}
```

All 3 x1 loadings are ok. By ok I mean all the navigation properties are null (as expected). However, when it loads x3 (includes the MotivoSubmissao navigation property), it CHANGES the x1 elements MotivoSubmissao value (from null to something else). I'm aware every select updates the DbSet cache, but how it is changing the x1 list if its a sepparate var?!

Comment: *I noticed that virtual fields were being loaded even with ´LazyLoadingEnabled´ set to true (default) and no Include() calls.* This is exactly how lazy loading is supposed to work. Actually you have to disable it or use eager load it if you don't want it.

Comment: I do want to use lazy loading (hence the ´LazyLoadingEnabled = true´), however virtual fields (navigation properties - lazy loading) fields are being loaded without even an Include() call. How come thats how its supposed to work?

Comment: `Include` has nothing in common with lazy loading. In fact it is the implementation of the eager loading. Lazy loading is, well, lazy - in other words, the first time you access a virtual property which is not already eager loaded, and lazy loading is enabled, then it's loaded, cached and returned to the caller.

Comment: Excuse me, Ivan. Can you enlighten me? What does Include have to do with it, then? Also, lazy fields should NOT be marked VIRTUAL?

Comment: Exactly the opposite. Only virtual properties are lazy loaded. May be I'm not explaining it well. Take a look at [Loading Related Entities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx), it explains everything.

Comment: Thanks for the link, Ivan. Before reading it, I updated my question to cover something else. Could you please take a look at it while I read your link? Thanks A LOT!

Comment: I did read it. Even if the lazy loading is off, still the objects are tracked inside the dbcontext, so the future queries return the same object instances, and when they get eager loaded, you see the changes in the other lists that you populated earlier. If you don't want that, you need to use [No-Tracking Queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556203.aspx). Hope that helps.

Comment: I understand that caching the results is something good approach. AsNoTracking did the job, although I don't quite understand how the DbContext's internal cache affect the `x1` object  which just allocated memory for a list. It looks like it has a pointer to that DbContext cache, which is not really clear. Btw, I meant that I was going to read your link, not you :P

Comment: He-he, I meant that I did read your update:) Anyway, forget about lists, think about **objects** inside the lists. Although they might not keep access to the `DbContext`, they are just **reference** types and `DbContext` has them in it's local cache and simply updating their properties :)

Comment: So do all elements in lists are references?! Really? Do you have some links I can take a look at?

Comment: Well, create some object (e.g. `var o = new SomeYourObject();`), add it to 2 lists, change some property of that object and you'll see it changed in both lists. This is basically what happens when `DbContext` is tracking (read - keep access to any object returned by your queries). Hope that helps. Take care.

Comment: Wow! What the hell... Do you know any container that will not keep references? This way I wouldnt need AsNoTracking().

Comment: Hey, this is how .NET classes work everywhere. Classes are called **reference** types, you know :) You really need `AsNoTracking` to tell the EF to not hold references and just return **new** objects.

Comment: Thanks, Ivan! Even thought this looks so damn weird lol